# two list floating left starting at center

Tags: html, css

```
<ul id="list1">
    <li><img src="whatever" /></li>
</ul>

<ul id="list2">
    <li><img src="whatever" /></li>
</ul>
```

All the content is `text-align: center;` so list1 is centered and list 2 should appear on the same line on the right side. But list2 starts at the line under list1.

```css
#list1 { list-style: none; }
#list1 li { display: inline; }
#list1 li img { width: 35px; height: 35px; }
#list1 li:first-child { padding-right: 20px; }
#list2 { list-style: none; }
#list2 li { display: inline; padding-right: 5px; float: right; }
#list2 li img { width: 32px; height: 32px; }
```

Any ideas or suggestions?

When im changing the display style to block at list1 then it is no longer `text-align:center`. So it Appears at the left side instead the mid.

Comment: `#list1 ul` is incorrect. "#list1" is the ul.

Answer (score 0):

You set the li to display inline, but the ul is still a block element. Set it to `display: inline-block;` or `display: block; float: left;` and perhaps try adding width too.